# Please recommend me a descriptive Chinese-English dictionary

Tags: dictionary

Most dictionaries will use several English words or phrases to explain Chinese words, but I'd like to find a dictionary that explains terms by sentences or descriptive words. For example:

创造: To build a thing from scratch

not:

创造: create

Comment: I think most online dictionaries will do.

Comment: Base I awareness ，There seems to be no such dictionary, or you can find a Chinese friend to help you explain

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Pleco dictionary, available as an Android/iPhone app, as that fits your description.

I think the ABC dictionary (available as a paid add-on to Pleco) is also valuable. As Chinese grammar is different from English grammar, it is useful to have (Chinese) grammatical information in each entry too, and ABC is very good for that.

Here is some general information about the ABC dictionary.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary
https://iphone.pleco.com/manual/229/abc.html